# Passing value from select to text input with javascript mystery

Tags: javascript, html

Have something I'm a bit perplexed by. I have written a very basic function to pass a value from an `<option>` element nested inside a `<select>` using the `onclick` event to another text input. It works fine in Firefox, but isn't working in any other browser, and I can't figure out why, as the console is not showing any errors.

The function looks like this:

```
function getSPO(spoc)
{
var answer = document.getElementById('ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.7.');
answer.value = spoc;
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<tr><td>Sponsor</td><td>
<select>
<option onclick="getSPO('0000001760')">Oxleas Nhs Trust</option>                                                              
<option onclick="getSPO('0000000876')">Sheffield Northern General Hospital</option>                                       
<option onclick="getSPO('0000001426')">The Royal Hospitals Nhs Trust</option>                                       
<option onclick="getSPO('0000001563')">Coventry Healthcare Nhs Trust</option>                                         
<option onclick="getSPO('0000002713')">Barking, Havering & Redbridge</option>
<option onclick="getSPO('0000012578')">Hammersmith Hospital Nhs Trust</option>                                                     
<option onclick="getSPO('0000012580')">Hammersmith Hospital Nhs Trust</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<option>` tag should not have `onclick` event. Change the code to:

```
<select onchange="getSPO(this.value);">
```

Using the `onchange` event of the drop down itself is the trick. Now, have each number as the value of each option:

```
<option value="0000001760">Oxleas Nhs Trust</option>                                                              
<option value="0000000876">Sheffield Northern General Hospital</option>
...
```